# How to use chart.js in angular

Tags: angular, chart.js

I'm trying implement chart.js in my angular project. There're not any error when compiling but the chart isn't showed. I don't know why.

This is chartjs.component.html

```
<canvas id="canvas">{{chart}}</canvas>
```

This is chartjs.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from "chart.js";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chartjs',
  templateUrl: './chartjs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chartjs.component.scss']
})
export class ChartjsComponent implements OnInit {
  public chart: any = null;

  ngOnInit() {
  this.chart = new Chart("canvas", {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});





  }

}
```

And i'm calling it in a selector called `<app-chartjs></app-chartjs>` in dashboard.component.html

I also added `"node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"` in the section script of angular.json.

Any soluction please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap `<app-chartjs></app-chartjs>` inside `*ngIf` or simply try this in `<app-chartjs>`

```
<div [hidden]="!chart">
    <canvas class="my-4 w-100" id="canvas" width="900" height="380">{{chart}}</canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Done. What is [hidden]="!chart" for?

Answer (score 1):

you have to create the new chart only in `ngAfterViewInit()`