# Failed to create chart

Tags: angular, chart.js

I would like to use doughnut chart in my angular app.
I installed chart js by using 'npm install chart.js --save.
But my problem is it didn't know Chart even if i import the class like this 'import {Chart} from 'chart.js'.
When i run the server i always have this error:

```
Chart.js:8459 Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item
```

here is my code in the ts

```
ngOnInit() {
this.PieChart = new Chart('pieChart', {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [9,7 , 3, 5, 2, 10],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    title:{
      text:"Bar Chart",
      display:true
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero:true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

}

Here is my code in the html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
        <canvas id="pieChart"></canvas>
      </div>
```

Comment: I created a fiddle from you code, everything seems to be correct -> https://jsfiddle.net/svoL0bfe/

Comment: You may try replacing `pieChart` to `document.getElementById('pieChart').getContext('2d');` in your `new Chart` function.

Answer (score 0):

i thin problem in getting ID

```
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

 var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
 var myChart = new Chart(ctx,{
    type: 'pie',
    data: data,
    options: options
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your chart is created before the view is rendered. And to do that, see this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53166341/3504273